# Jquery Ajax php - .one function not work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is a simple test page. The issue is that for the first click on the anchor tag, i get back the value, but when i click it for the second time seems that ajax stop to work. Please, tell me how can i solve it. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").one('click', function(e) {
        $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: { 
        play: $(this).attr("href") },
        success: function(msg) {
            //alert(msg);
            $("#playarea").append(msg);
          }
        });
    e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>

<div><a id="run1" href="link1">Test1...</a></div>
<div><a id="run1" href="link2">Test2...</a></div>
<div><a id="run1" href="link3">Test3...</a></div>
<div><a id="run1" href="link4">Test4...</a></div>
<div><a id="run1" href="link5">Test5...</a></div>

<div id="playarea"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you think`.one()` does?

Comment: I think you mean `.on()` http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: if i use ".on", each times i click on a link i get back the value of (msg). So ".on" in my case not solve the issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **[`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** instead of **[`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)** since the `one()` will attach the click event just for one click then detach it.

> **`.one()` Description:** Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element per event type.

```
$("a").on('click', function(e) {
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    data: { 
    play: $(this).attr("href") },
    success: function(msg) {
        //alert(msg);
        $("#playarea").html(msg);
      }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**NOTE :** If you want to override the old result use `html()` instead of `append()`.
Hope this helps.

Comment: You don't want to get the result one time using `one()` also not every time using `on()`?! sorry but i can't understand your desired behviour exactly..

Comment: Look here http://fb03.netsons.org/ajaxtest.php
I can't use jsfiddle because there is a little php part...
Try to click more times on a link and see the result...

Comment: If you want to override the old result use `html()` instead of `append()`.

Comment: its just want i want, ONE time. But after one time, if i click again on the same link, ajax do not work more

Comment: @War10ck The issue was the .append(), i should use .html() instead... :(